# IMPORTRANGE only if cell = X

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, importrange

I have two Google Sheets and am populating data from the 1st to the 2nd successfully using IMPORTRANGE.

```
=importrange("key",address(row(),column(),,,"Sheet1"))
```

This formula allows me to fill down in the same row of the 2nd spreadsheet and have the data dynamically populated from the 1st.

Now I want to be able to only have the data show from each cell IF it equals a specific string.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want imported data to appear if it is equal to some string ("want this" in my example); otherwise the cell should remain blank. This can be done with `arrayformula(if(...` as follows:

```
=arrayformula(if(importrange("url", "range") = "want this", "want this", ))
```

The third argument of `if` is intentionally left blank; this makes the cell truly blank (which isn't the same as containing the empty string `""`).

Comment: So I am trying to use =arrayformula(if(importrange("key",address(row(),column()) = "123 Here St", "123 Here St", ))   which comes back with a "wrong number of arguments" to IF error.

Comment: Looks like `importrange("key",address(row(),column())` is missing a closing parenthesis.